# Add cc and bcc in php mail

Tags: php, email

How can i add cc and bcc in the following script

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back:  $property_id \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message , $proptitle";
$recipient = "myemailid@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='#' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Did you look at [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)? There is planty of information there. Search (ctrl + f) for "cc" and you might find something useful.

Comment: Be careful using the other person's email in the "from" field, you should put their email in the reply-to, see [Common Contact Form Mistakes](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarccontactus/)

Answer (score 8):

You need to set headers for setting cc and bcc:

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: My Name <myemail@example.com>'. "\r\n";
//Multiple CC can be added, if we need (comma separated);
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss1@example.com, myboss2@example.com' . "\r\n";
//Multiple BCC, same as CC above;
$headers .= 'Bcc: myboss3@example.com, myboss4@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message,  $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$mailheader .= 'Cc: joe@bloggs.com' . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'Bcc: john@doe.com' . "\r\n";
```

As per the PHP documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You will extend your $mailheader.

$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n" .
"Bcc: someone@example.com' . "\r\n";

Answer (score -1):

```
**First off all you have to concat $recipient with cc and Bcc variable use like this**
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back:  $property_id \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message , $proptitle";
$recipient = "myemailid@gmail.com";
$recipient. = "CC: cc@gmail.com\r\n";
$recipient .= "BCC: bcc@gmail.com\r\n";   
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='#' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```